# Collapse all children of a parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Similar stuff has been asked earlier but I could not find this.

```
<article class="fyre-comment-article>
    <div class="fyre-comment-wrapper">Parent Post
        <div class="fyre-outer-comment-container"> Contains all child
            <div class="fyre-comment-article">Single child with the same pattern as parent </div>
        </div>
</article>
```

I was able to handle the collapsing when parent div closes before child and is not in the parenthesized format.

How to collapse (onclick) the Parent Post by only showing "Parent Post Details" and same should be applied internally to each Parent Post.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class attribute in article tag is missing a closing quote and one of the div tags isn't getting closed at all.

But basically you can just do:

```
$('.fyre-comment-article').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.fyre-outer-comment-container').toggle();
});
```

which will show/hide the two most nested divs when you click on the text inside the article tag.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VhbwU/).

---

### Update

If you're adding elements to DOM after the script loads, then the binding doesn't work for them and you can fix it for instance by using `.on()` method, like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.fyre-comment-article', function() {
  $(this).find('.fyre-outer-comment-container').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Remember he's using `class` name `.fyre-outer-comment-container` this will target every single one of them on the page.

Comment: Good point, changed the answer to only affect children of clicked element.

Comment: I had managed to use $(this).find to get the children element but somehow toggle is behaving abnormally. Works at times and doesn't work on the next deployment (page-refresh).
If I try on chrome console, it always works. Any specific reason?

Comment: Checked your page and updated the answer with what worked on the page, when I changed the JS locally on my browser. Give it a shot?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also, if its' not too much, why does it happen?

Comment: Because if you use `bind()` and then add elements to DOM dynamically, no binding is done to those latter elements, even if they match the matcher. It's a long story and you can read more here for instance: [differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live-vs-delegate-vs-on](http://www.elijahmanor.com/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live-vs-delegate-vs-on/).

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

HTML:

```
<article class="fyre-comment-article">
    <div class="fyre-comment-wrapper">Parent Post
        <div class="fyre-outer-comment-container"> Contains all child
            <div class="fyre-comment-article-inner">Single child with the same pattern as parent </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('.fyre-comment-wrapper').click(function() {
        var $article = $(this).find('.fyre-comment-article-inner');
        if (!$article.is(':visible')) {
            $article.slideDown();  //or .fadeIn() or .show()
        } else {
            $article.slideUp();    //or .fadeOut() or .hide()
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f55ta/1/)

**Edit**

If you want 'Contains all child' label to appear and disappear too, you have to write

```
.find('.fyre-outer-comment-container');
```

instead of

```
.find('.fyre-comment-article-inner');
```

[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/f55ta/2/)